# How do I include dependencies in my android library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am writing an android sdk and I now want to distribute it but I am having problems with its dependencies. I am using gradle and android studio.

My sdk has a dependency on volley and gson and I have them added as jars with in my sdk. When ever I try to create an aar or a jar to use within a separate client app I always get a crash when ever my sdk tries to reference volley as it wasnt included in either the aar or jar.
Any ideas on how I should be doing this? I have looked into creating fat jars with out much success.

I have also tried using remote dependencies like below but even after a gradle build in the client app both volley and gson are still not included.
This is currently what I have in my sdk build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

then with in the client build gradle I have

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name:'mysdk-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
}
```

I am using `./gradlew clean build` to build the aar and jar of my sdk
Can anyone tell me the correct way to include dependencies in my own lib?

Comment: This is a very concise and clear question.  It captures exactly what I wanted to ask, but didn't have to because I found yours!  Kudos.

Comment: How did you solve it? The accepted answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client, change your dependencies block like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name:'mysdk-1.0.0', ext:'aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

This should pull in your transitive dependencies as well.

Comment: Where do I call this compile(name: ext:)? I am trying calling it in my client's  build.gradle and it gives error on mysdk-1.0.0. I thought mysdk-1.0.0 is just a label which will be given to the resulting jar/aar. What should I do?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Does the AAR files even have the dependency information inside of it? Isn't a POM file required?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to include the transitive dependencies of your library in your client app, you'll need to create a proper maven compatible package that contains a pom.xml. This pom will describe the dependencies of your lib, so that client can pull those deps transitively when they include your lib.

See this tutorial(updated link): http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/locally-release-an-android-library-for-jcenter-or-maven-central-inclusion/

You don't have to upload the artifact anywhere during development, just use your local maven repo as a target, and have `mavenLocal()` as a repository for your client app.
This way, you'll be able to refer to your lib as a standard maven dependency using 
`compile 'com.mysdk:mysdk:1.0.0'`

Comment: Dead link, now it's [http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/locally-release-an-android-library-for-jcenter-or-maven-central-inclusion/](http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/locally-release-an-android-library-for-jcenter-or-maven-central-inclusion/)